# How does deauth protection (IEEE_802.11w-2009) work?

Tags: wireless, wpa2, 802.1x

I read a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11w-2009) on IEEE_802.11w-2009 and I wonder how does it work with WPA2. In other words, how do I turn it on in my Linux kernel? If I enable it both in it and in an OpenWRT router, am I resistant to regular deauth attack? Does IEEE_802.11w-2009 have any disadvantages or limitations that are worth noting off-hand?